# Allow access to a locally stored XML from Internet Explorer9

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I'm developing a webapp in HTML5 that must work locally.

Is an app to design a datamodel, and it should parse tables informations from an XML well-formed file and render them in the html. I want to create custom views, telling the script wich tables parse from the XML passing their names via the GET parameters in th URL.

To do this, i'm using jQUery's `$.ajax` method, I developed it in Firefox and everything goes well.
But I need it working on IE9, and using both the $.ajax and the XMLHttpRequest I receive an "Access denied" error.

Here the script working on Firefox:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // // rilevo la stringa  dell'URL che contiene i nomi delle tabelle da visualizzare
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    // se c'è
    if (query){
        // alert('query= '+query);
        var tabelle = query.split('&');
        // alert('lunghezza array tabelle= '+tabelle.length);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "tables.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false,
            success: function(xml) {
                alert('start loading tables');
                // var i_success = 0;
                for(var i_success=0; i_success<tabelle.length; i_success++){
                    $(xml).find('tabella').each(function(){
                        // alert('pars+write tabella '+i_success+': id= '+tabelle[i_success]);
                        if ($(this).find('id').text() == tabelle[i_success]) {
                        var id = $(this).find('id').text();
                            // //verifico che la tabella sia tra quelle passatemi nell'URL
                            // var found = $.inArray(id, tabelle) > -1;
                            var classe = $(this).attr('classe');
                            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                            $('<div class="drag tab" id="'+id+'"></div>').html('<h2 class="th">'+title+'</h2>').appendTo('#content');
                            var i_celle = 0;

                            $(this).find('cella').each(function() {
                                var id_cella = $(this).find('id_cella').text();
                                var content = $(this).find('content').text();
                                $('<div class="td '+id_cella+'">'+content+'</div>').appendTo('#'+id);
                                i_celle++;
                            }); 
                        // continue;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    });// end find each
                } //end for
            },//end success

            complete: function(){
                toggleFields();
                connections();
                toggleBg();
                alert('complete');
            },//end complete
            error: function(richiesta,stato,errori){
                $("#content").html("<strong>Caricamento delle tabelle fallito:</strong><br/>"+stato+" "+errori);
            }//end error
        }); //end ajax
    } else {
        alert('Non sono state fornite tabelle da visualizzare...');
    }

});`
```

Here the code I'm trying to implement for IE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // // rilevo la stringa  dell'URL che contiene i nomi delle tabelle da visualizzare
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1); 
    // se c'è
    if (query){
        alert('query= '+query);
        var tabelle = query.split('&');
        alert('lunghezza array tabelle= '+tabelle.length);

        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            alert('Questo browser supporta XMLHttpRequest! :)');
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            alert('XMLHttpRequest creata con successo');

            xmlhttp.open("GET","tables.xml",true);
            alert('richiesta aperta');
            xmlhttp.send();
            alert('Request inviata con successo');
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            alert('XMLHttpRequest non supportata da questo browser');
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

    } else {   
        alert('Non sono state fornite tabelle da visualizzare...');
    }// end if query

}); // end document.ready
```

Can anyone help me please? I'm getting crazy..

Comment: One of the benefits of using jQuery is that you do not have to do anything special to get code running on multiple browsers. You should not need what you call the IE code. The code that runs on FF shoudl work on all browsers. If it does not there will be a little mistake that you can fix and then it will run on all browsers.

Comment: Oh yes, I know it. jQuery makes a lot of control and ensures degradation for me.

Comment: Oh yes, I know it. jQuery makes a lot of control and ensures degradation for me.
But I know the problem, and that's why I'm trying to re-code: IE blocks the XMLHttprequest to local files. Firefox doesn't. And Chrome does the block but if you call it with the '--disable-web-security' option from command line the local file access is allowed.

Comment: Do you mean you are not using a web server?

Comment: Yes. I mean I'm creating a local webapp. It has to be stored on disk, without webserver. Just needs to be opened by a web browser.
Unfortunately, I have to pass some parameters in the URL string (each datamodel view loads only the tables I pass in the string) and the links must start from an SWF embedded in a zoom plugin that works fine only in IE.
A very big mess, and I have no choice cause I'm working on another person's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix.

I decided to pass all data in a JSON object INLINE.

You can do it in the HTML DOM, using

```
<script type="application/json" id="stuff>

json code here

</script>
```

and call it in js using
    var myVar=JSON.parse(document.getElementById('stuff').innerHTML);
This is HTML% valid: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-script-element .

I decided to write it directly in the js, and to call it like a var. 
    var tabObj = {"tabelle":
    json code
    };
I have to understand yet if I have to parse it or if is not mandatory.

That's all folks. Thanks for the help, I know it was a strange question.